# How to group rows based on values in one specific column?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, data-cleaning

Assume I have a set of data such as

> (student_id,,,,, topic_of_interests)

Now the topic of interests can vary from hiking, reading, and sleeping. I need to group the students based on these topic of interests, each student has multiple comma separated entries in topic_of_interests. How do I go about doing this?

End result I need is a mapping such that querying one topic of interest gives me all the students associated with it.
Edit: the data is quite large and I don't know the values of different topic of interests.

Comment: "*each student has multiple comma separated entries in topic_of_interests*" - not a good idea. You should read up on database normalization

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic many-to-many relationship.
You need two main tables `students`, `topics` and a so-called *bridge table* (or *mappings*):

```
create table students_topics (
    student_id int references students,
    topic_id int references topics,
    primary key (student_id, topic_id)
);
```

See [full example in rextester](http://rextester.com/YZWN17947).

---

If you want to easily get such an analysis you should rebuild your actual table to the model described above.

With your actual data structure try this approach:

```
select topic, array_agg(student_id)
from (
    select student_id, trim(topic) topic
    from students, 
    unnest(string_to_array(topic_of_interests, ',')) topic
    ) s
group by 1;
```

Comment: Edited the part about not knowing the value-set of topic of interests first hand, and its a large dataset.

Comment: Read the updated answer. You really should normalize your data, **especially** when the table is large.